# I keep getting an error Page Isn't Working when I try to post an image to an html file using php

Tags: php, html

The part of the code that is giving me a problem is:

```
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} 
else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
   
    if(($_SESSION['name']) <> 'Support'){

        $fp = fopen("log.html", 'a');
        fwrite($fp, "<div class='msgln'>" "<img src='<?php echo $target_file; ?>' />" " 
            <br /><span class='time-right'>(".date("g:i A").")</span><br /><br /> 
            </div>");
        fclose($fp);
    }
    else{

    $fp = fopen("log.html", 'a');
        fwrite($fp, "<div class='msgln_right'>" "<img src='<?php echo $target_file; ?>' 
        />" "<br /><span class='time-right'>(".date("g:i A").")</span><br /><br /> 
        </div>");
    fclose($fp);

   }
}
```

}

It will upload the image but I cannot post the image to the html page.  Please help

Comment: Remove all the occurrences of `" "` in your code and try again.

Comment: Turn on php error reporting then you can see the exact error message

Comment: Thank you, I have tried both and no luck yet.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: I got it fixed.  I took the code out of fwrite($fp, <....>); and put it into a variable $text.  I put the variable into the fwrite($fp, $text); and it is now working great.  I also took out the occurrences of " ".